# Difference between width & height and the style image attribute

Tags: html, css, image, height, width

Why use a style image attribute rather than just coding width and height for each image?

Comment: You should start be learning about the principle of [separation of concerns](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_concerns#HTML.2C_CSS.2C_JavaScript)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because using style you can use the same width and height in different images. This is very useful if you want all to be the same size. When you want to change something you only have to change one time,not all your images.